# How to load components (containing assets) from npm package in a Single-Spa application?

Tags: angular, assets, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have an application build using [Single-Spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) and it consist of:

- Root Config App *(hosted on http://localhost:3000)*
- App1 *(Angular application hosted on http://localhost:3001)*

**App1** has a dependency (npm package) **Dep1**.
**Dep1** provides **img-preview.png** file and **PreviewComponent** (which I use in App1) with this html:

```html
<img src="/assets/images/img-preview.png">
```

When I open my app (by Root Config App) it tries to load the **img-preview.png** file from *http://localhost:3000/assets/images/img-preview.png*, but it won't work, because the file is served on *http://localhost:3001*.

For the assets that are directly under **App1** I use the **assetUrl** helper method provided by single-spa-angular([angular-assets](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular#angular-assets)).
However I cannot find any solution to load assets that are defined and used within npm dependencies. I cannot modify **Dep1**. The only way that seems feaseable is to replace **Dep1** with my custom code, but that's just ludicrous.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense; when you have an app dependency it doesn't mean it is served on a different host (different port in this case). You should install the dependency properly with a package manager like npm and then you will be able to use the assets from within the same origin.

Comment: On a side note, SPA means single page application. So *"Single-Spa application"* means literally: *"Single single page application application"*.

Comment: "Single-Spa" is the name of the framework I'm using, it's a solution for Microfrontend. Yes, the dependency **Dep1** is installed within App1, so since it's a part of this app, it's also bundled together with it and hosted on http://localhost:3001, but the Root Config App is served on http://localhost:3000 and it resolves all assets (even those from App1) using localhost:3000 not 3001 - that's why it cannot access them.

Comment: Learned something new today, never heard of that framework. Also I don't have the proper knowledge to help you any further with this issue. Hope you get some help of someone else familiar with this setup.

Comment: Yeah, the description was a bit misleading, I'll try to be more precise in the future. Thanks anyway ;)